# html width acting weird at smaller screen

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to optimize my website for smaller screens like handys.

But when I try to test it for screens smaller then 400px the body isn't the full width of the screen anymore.

[image]

this is how it looks for a 360px widescreen.
It says the HTML width is 360px, but it isn't the full width of the screen.

Comment: Is it because you have zoom set at 95%?

Comment: could you post some relevant with the question `CSS` code please.

Comment: Oh, I actually found the solution by myself. Weird that I found it 3 minutes after asking the question, but trying to solve it like 2 hours. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @carlos.gmz, would be nice if you could share your solution... I'm having (what looks like) the same problem...